# Advanced SQL query to create a dynamic query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to create query to select columns on the basis of values contained by that column.

Basically I want to apply a condition for selecting a particular column.

For example, say there are columns c1,c2,c3. These columns can have any values from oral, written, practical in any sequence. I want to retrieve a column containing value `oral`, but I don't know which column contains this value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your database design is not optimal.

Instead of using several columns with similar meanings, it's better to use a separate table and store this data in rows rather than columns.

A general rule in relational databases is that every column should store **a different kind of data** related to the object represented by a row. If all your columns store similar kinds of data, turn them into rows in a new table and use a foreign key to connect between the two tables.